# Asynchronous Download in Queue using NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsoperationqueue

I have an application where user can download documents. User has option to download multiple documents. Multiple download shall happen one after the other in a sequence (once a document is finished downloading the other shall start automatically).

Currently I'm using NSURLConnection for Asynchronously downloading data (Single Document at a time).

How do i go about achieving this possibly using NSOperation Queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than queuing up NSOperations why not store an NSArray of download 'items' (e.g. the URL you want to download), then when one of your NSURLConnections finishes downloading you can check the array, and if there is anything in it you can kick off a new NSURLConnection download, then remove the item you just downloaded.

That way, if you store the download items array on disk in between each download, if your app crashes or is terminated, it can start up where it left off.

Answer (score 0):

Create `NSOperation` object and add it to `NSOperationQueue`. follow [this](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/)

link to crate NSOperation and NSOperationQueue.

Then set maximum concurrency operation to one using `NSOperationQueue` method

```
setMaxConcurrentOperationCount
```